# ssis package format in excel

Tags: sql-server-2008, business-intelligence

i need  create an ssis package ouput in this following format in excel

```
           India
          Employee report
```

Report run date : 24/01/2012

```
id    name      address
1     manoj     blore
2     manu      chennai
3     anu       chennai
4     vani      mumbai
```

write now my dataset contains like this

```
   id    name      address
    1     manoj     blore
    2     manu      chennai
    3     anu       chennai
    4     vani      mumbai
```

these things will be dynamic

```
     India
              Employee report
Report run date : 24/01/2012
```

i can hold all these dyanamic values in an variables and  use it

how can i get the above format result pls let me know  how  to go ahead.

i wanted the result  to be  shown like the above  format

is  there any solution we can get it done ,i am using sql server  r2

Thanks
Prince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is to create script task that connects to Excel sheet and creates rows with that additional data.

Here is some useful links:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3919016/Accessing-Excel-Via-ADONET-Using-SSIS-Script-Task.htm