# how to get row count palced as a footer in flat file

Tags: ssis

I need to add an footer in flat file destinatiion as an row count.  am importing data from oledb to flat file, i need the count of the records placed as a footer in flat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this similar to this:

> [ssis package format in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092744/ssis-package-format-in-excel/9093668#9093668)

But in this case you can:

> 1. Create variable of type int (package scope).
> 2. Add Row Count Component in your data flow and in Variable Name put you var.
> 3. Create script task that will connect to your txt file and add additonal row with rowcount.

Hope it will help.